# How to migrate gitlab backups to new server which has latest gitlab version

Tags: git, gitlab, bitnami, gitlab-ci

I am trying to migrate my gitlab backups for my old server to new server. my old server has gitlab (gitlab-6.5.1-0) and my new server has gitlab version (gitlab 6.6.5-omnibus). i taken backup from my old server using the following command

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

and when i try to restore this backup in new server using this command

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1395394855
```

I am getting the following output

```
Unpacking backup ... done
GitLab version mismatch:
  Your current GitLab version (6.6.5) differs from the GitLab version in the backup!
  Please switch to the following version and try again:
  version: 6f6f1588ba5123f156ee3b0635a061745b71fcde
```

I tried searching for solution . but in all documents its says **The backup is already migrated to the previous version**. but none of them describes how to migrate backups . Any solution regarding this is Appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

This error message is produced by [`lib/backup/manager.rb#L87-L92`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/f1d8efb7700fb95b98924ffe2e65dd08f7f376c9/lib/backup/manager.rb#L87-L92):

```ruby
  settings = YAML.load_file("backup_information.yml")
  ENV["VERSION"] = "#{settings[:db_version]}" if settings[:db_version].to_i > 0

  # restoring mismatching backups can lead to unexpected problems
  if settings[:gitlab_version] != Gitlab::VERSION
    puts "GitLab version mismatch:".red
```

It seems to force an incremental backup, as [described in this comment](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1796#issuecomment-19919648):

> I have faced the same issue when restoring the backup to a new server.
>
> `backup.rake` checks GITLAB commit number at time of backup is taken and when you are restoring to the same branch name from latest check out.
>
> I have to:
>
> - delete `5-2-stable` and
> - check out again `5-2-stable` with the same commit hash ( `git checkout -b 5-2-stable COMMIT-HASH`),
> - ran all tasks as installing a fresh `5-2-stable` release with same `config/gitlab.yml`, `config/database.yml`.
> - Then I have copied `backup.tar` file into default `/home/git/gitlab/tmp/backups` and ran `restore rake` task.
>
> It worked without any problem. Then I have followed 5-2-stable to 5-3-stable upgrade and it went all well.

Comment: hi vonc. my previous version was installed using Bitnami. in this version there is no dir called /home/git all data resides in /opt/gitlab.5.xx dir

Comment: @NaveenSubramani then I am not sure. The migration process might not work out of the box. A good case to mention to GitLab support, then. https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues?state=open

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, the backup archive is created by (gitlab-6.5.1-0) and can't be restored using (gitlab 6.6.5-omnibus).

For simple solution, I'd recommend installing `gitlab-6.5.1-omnibus` and restored your backup archive first. Then, do the upgrade through linux package system. Run `sudo gitlab-rake db:migrate` if you encountered any problem related to databases

Answer (score 1):

According to the Gitlab official documentation on [***Backing up and restoring GitLab***](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html):

> You can **only restore a backup to exactly the same version and type (CE/EE) of GitLab** on which it was created. The best way to migrate your repositories from one server to another is through backup restore.

So, update your gitlab on OLD server first (i.e. 6.5.1-0 -> 6.6.5 ), then follow the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html) will do.