# Gitlab migrate from 6.x to 8 in docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, migrate, gitlab-ci, gitlab-8

I'm currently running a gitlab 6, which I've installed locally. Now I'm trying to migrate my services to docker. Luckily there is a gitlab docker container, but it is version 8 and provides the tree volumes `/etc/gitlab`, `/var/log/gitlab` and `/var/opt/gitlab`. But I only have gitlab files in `/home/git/`.

Is there any way of migrating a gitlab 6 to version 8 in a docker?

I know this question is somehow related to [How to migrate gitlab backups to new server which has latest gitlab version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557785/how-to-migrate-gitlab-backups-to-new-server-which-has-latest-gitlab-version) but this is only within a major release.

Comment: I don't think this really relates to docker, but to gitlab in general. So, I think you'll have to install GitLab 7 as an intermediate step, i.e. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/6.x-or-7.x-to-7.14.md, and http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/update/7.14-to-8.0.html

Answer (score 2):

Given that there's no direct upgrade path from GitLab 6 to 8, you'd probably have to;

- Upgrade your GitLab install from 6 to 7.14; https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/6.x-or-7.x-to-7.14.md
- Upgrade from 7.14 to 8 http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/update/7.14-to-8.0.html

After that, you should be able to run the [Gitlab CE image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) from Docker Hub, and mount your existing data as a volume, using [the instructions in the documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/)

Note that the upgrade steps are not specific to running GitLab in a Docker container