# Copy Gitlab repositories to another Gitlab server through filesystem

Tags: linux, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I had a `gitlab` server of 7.6.2 version with some repositories. Now this server was upgraded by newest Ubuntu and it has an empty `gitlab` server of version 12.0.1. I also have a HDD backup from old `gitlab` server.

I need to move all repositories from old gitlab server to the new one. I tried to copy `.git` repositories from `/var/opt/gitlab/repositories/user/` to the similar location of the new server with disabled hashed repositories storage, but it has no effect.

I also tried to create an empty repository with e.g. name `test` and replace `test.git` directory on new server from directory from old one, but there is no effect neither.

I tried to find file from created test repository named `test.txt` by `find` command in whole server file system, but there is no such file was found (but this file exists in the `gitlab` repository).

My question is: where repositories of `gitlab` server are stored and how can I copy it from backup of old server HDD to the new server file system (I can not run both instances of `gitlab` because I have only one machine. Running backup of old server as virtual machine's rootfs is also impossible by some reasons).

**Upd.**
It is not duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557785/how-to-migrate-gitlab-backups-to-new-server-which-has-latest-gitlab-version) because I have no backups of old `gitlab` server made by `gitlab`, I have only backup of filesystem of machine it was installed on. I also can not run old server to pull repositories because its machine was upgraded. Only thing I have from old server: its filesystem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate gitlab backups to new server which has latest gitlab version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557785/how-to-migrate-gitlab-backups-to-new-server-which-has-latest-gitlab-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to migrate repositories (ie: no issues, pipelines, etc), it's better to clone each repository and upload it again (one by one, or using a batch command):

```
cd /var/opt/gitlab/repositories/...
git remote add newserver url
git push --all newserver url
```

Instead, if you need to migrate all features, it's better to restore the server backup and upgrade OS and Gitlab in place... even if it's a long road between 7 and 12, and you probably neeed to make multiple steps.

Comment: Problem is that old server can not be started after system upgrade and I have only its filesystem backup, so, I can not pull from old server

Comment: Those files you found in `/var/opt/gitlab/repositories/` are called "bare" repositories. You can push from there.

Comment: [`git pull --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---all) and [`git push --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---all) do different things. `git push --all` is ok here but not `git pull --all`.

Comment: thanks @phd I also updated my answer after shadasviar clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

**Careful, this might cause massive breakage, experiment on a scratch system.**

The git repositories should be the same, so I'd try just copying the contents over. The user information and ancillary stuff is probably different.

Another path would be to set up the old system, and upgrade that one. Version by version, if need be.

Last resort is to clone the old repositories and upload them into the new system.

Comment: What content should I copy? Where repositories are located on file system for copying it? I copy directories from question, but it had no effect: these `.git` directories are not valid git repositories